# What is the dimension of the space spanned by the cubic polynomials $aX^{3} + bX$ in $k$ variables?

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

So, $X=(x_1, x_2, ..., x_k)$ and $a, b$ are reals. I know that the dimension of the space spanned by the harmonic cubic polynimials in $k$ variables is $k+2\choose 3$. These are not harmonic, but have a specified form. It can be shown that the dimension does not exceeds ${k\choose 3} + k(k-1)+2k$, since there are $k$ monomials of the form $x_i^3$, $k(k-1)$ monomials of the form $x_i^2x_j$, $k\choose 3$ monomials of the form $x_ix_jx_k$, and $k$ monomials of the form $x_i$. This sums up to ${k\choose 3} + k(k-1)+2k$, which is larger than $k+2\choose 3$. Now, can the previous bound be improved (perahaps, to be equal to $k+2\choose 3$)?.